# Data in txt file won't change after user input [C++]

Tags: c++, loops, input, output, text-files

```
string line;
fstream search;
short loop = 0;
const int SIZE = 6;
string weight[SIZE];
int index[6] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int i;
int choice;
string weightChange;

search.open("name.txt"); //Opens the text file in which the user details are stored
if (search.is_open())
{
    cout << endl;
    while (getline(search, line)) { //While the program searches for the lines in the text file
        if (line.find("Current Weight(KG): ") != string::npos) { //If the string "Name" isnt the last word on the line
            weight[loop] = line; //Assings the strings read from the text file to the array called weight
            cout << index[loop] << ". " << weight[loop] << endl; //Outputs the index array which loops through the numbers in the array and outputs the weight variable which loops through the strings in the array
            loop++; //Iterates the loop 
        }
    }
        cout << "Which index would you like to change?" << endl;
        cout << "1, 2, 3, 4 or 5" << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        cout << "Weight being changed is " << weight[choice - 1] << endl;

        switch (choice) //Uses switch to allow the user to enter a number from the menu and then performs that function based on the user's input
        {
        case 1: //If the user enters choice 1, then the first weight index will be changed
            cout << "What would you like to change the user's weight to?" << endl;
            cin >> weightChange;
            weightChange = weight[1];

            search >> weight[1];

            cout << endl;
            break;
        }
}
```

So i have a program that will read user's current weights from a text file using a loop. I then have to get a user input on which person's weight they would like to change. When the input what user whose weight they would like to change, they are asked what they would like to change the wiehg to. The program runs fine, but when they enter the new weight, it doesnt change anything in the txt file.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but shouldn't it be `weight[1] = weightChange` and not the other way around?

Comment: If I understand correctly you are trying to read from user and write to file, right ?
To do it, you need to write to file (operator <<), and you are reading from file (operator >>)

Maybe you have to change >> operator to <<, (search >> weight[1];) Should be (search << weight[1];)

If you invert your operator, I think your logic will not work as you expect, but it is a logic problem;

Look at std::fstream::open documentation http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/, maybe you need to change mode parameter.

Comment: Hint: This never writes to the file. Tip: Make a function that loads the file and returns the data, and another that takes data and re-writes the file.